# Date And Time Shown Whithout Updating AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, date, time, static

I am currently trying to show local date and time (of any user that will view my animation)
in a dynamic text field (instance name:DateTime).
i found many tutorials and methods but what i want to do is show current date and time **whithout** updating seconds/minutes or anything. Just static date and time when the movie entered the frame.
I am using ActionScript3.

I apologise if i am not very clear. can't really express my self in english

Thanks in advance

Comment: The tutorials that you saw definitely using some timer to update seconds/minutes. Just setting the current date/time onces and removing the timer should be enough.

Answer (score 2):

```
//...
var d:Date = new Date();
var dateText:String = d.toLocaleString();
DateTime.text = dateText; 
//suggestion: dont use capital letters for instance names
//keep them for class names
```

Date is top level afaik so you don't need to import it.

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Date.html

also if you post some code with your question next time it is easier to help